# Cordova Google Fit plugin authorization failure

Tags: cordova, google-fit

I'm trying to connect to Fitness API using this cordova plugin:
https://github.com/2dvisio/cordova-plugin-googlefit

I've enabled Fitness api in google console developer,
 genereted SHA-1 using
 `keytool -list -v -keystore degub.keystore` 
and added it to fingerprint list in developer console.

After calling 
`window.plugins.googlefit.getStuff1` 
nothing happens, no error or success callback is called.

I've noticed in logcat this message:
`V BaseAuthAsyncOperation: access token request failed: com.google.android.gms`
and i suppose this is the reason of failure.

Is it an plugin issue or my setup mistake?

Will be greatful for any help

Comment: This now reflect a very old version of the plugin